# How to get the text from an anchor tag?

Tags: python, splinter

I would like to get the text from all anchor tag which has class="ip_click" in the page. Here's an exactly example that I'm trying to get:

```
<a href="#" class="ip_click">177.1.1.1</a>
<a href="#" class="ip_click">177.2.2.2</a>
```

I want to get "177.1.1.1" and "177.2.2.2" and how much other

```
<a href="#" class="ip_click">Something here</a>
```

Exist in the page, so I tried:

```
ip = browser.find_by_css("ip_click")
for i in ip:
    print i
```

But the Firefox closes and nothing is displayed in terminal. Furthermore, in terminal no error is shown.

Comment: If you use css_selector, specify `.`  to mention it's a class  `browser.find_by_css(".ip_click")`

Comment: It was so obviusly but I didn't know that. So I added "." to 'ip_click' and ".text" to 'print i' and it worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [css_selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors), specify `.` for accessing the elements with the given classname.

```
ips = browser.find_by_css(".ip_click")
for ip in ips:
    print ip.text
```